# How to remove escape characters when JSON is added to model in spring rest controller

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-rest

I am fetching JSON stored in DB (JSON is stored as a string in DB) and adding it to the model object in the controller.

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/all" )
public void getJson(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Model model){

    String json = serviceDao.getResponseJson(); 
    System.out.println(json); //Output: {"Response":[{"Id":"1","Name":"GAD"},{"Id":"2","Name":"GBD"}],"Status":"Success"}
    model.addAttribute("result",json);
}
```

But when I invoke the service from a browser, escape characters are added the response.

> http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/all.json
>
> {"result":"{\"Response\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"GAD\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"GBD\"}],\"Status\":\"Success\"}"}

Can you please help me on the way to send the JSON object to the client in a webservice without escape characters.

Comment: Send the JSON as object, instead of String. Or make the return type to String and return the JSON directly.

Comment: If you are using spring, you can use @ResponseBody and directly return your class object instead of String.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427279/how-do-i-pass-this-escaped-json-with-gson-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding the string to model return JSON directly

```
@RequestMapping(value="/all")
public @ResponseBody String getJson(){
   //Logic
    return json; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceAll:

```
String json = serviceDao.getResponseJson();

if (json != null && !json.isEmpty()) {
    model.addAttribute("result", json.replaceAll("\\\\", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work definitely.

```
 String str = "result':'\'\'Respon'";
 String result = str.replaceAll("\\\'", ""); 
 Log.e("Result",result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring, you can use `@ResponseBody` and directly return your class object instead of String.

You can refer example given in this [link](http://codetutr.com/2013/04/09/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody/).

Also don't forget to include maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```